# how to search a table by looping through an array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array of names and I need to fetch the full name of each from a database. In the code below I've managed to get a list of the user's friends/pals and then turn that string into an array. But I've failed to fetch the full name of the names in the array, help please :(

Here is my model

```
public function getPals(){
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('pals', array('username' => $username));

    foreach ($query->result() as $row){

        $palString = $row->pal_list;   //returns a string "james,nash" from db

        $palsArray = explode(",", $palString);

        foreach ($palsArray as $pals) {

            $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('username' => $pals));

            foreach ($query->result() as $row){

                $pal = $row->full_name;

                //nothing is returned, am pretty sure nash exists in the db
                echo $pal;
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try debugging the entire query `print_r($query->result());` before your last foreach. What is the result. If no result, start working backwards and see if your $palsArray actually has content. Would help if you were sure if `james` and `nash` exist in the database.

Comment: oooh! i got it, the database was empty. thank you